# Modificar a cor do DatePicker

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando modificar a cor de fundo do meu datepicker do jquery , eu procurei na internet algumas soluções me traziam este codigo:

```
.ui-datepicker {
color:white;
background-color: red;
 background: red; 
}
```

So que ele não modifica o calendario , ele fica da mesma forma :
[image]

O código de invocação dele é o seguinte:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#calendario").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']
    });
});
</script>
<p>Data: <input type="text" id="calendario" /></p>
```

Eu consigo mudar a cor de fundo pra torna-lo legivel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informe o elemento das datas e informe a importancia:

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar{
background-color:red !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo , deu certo!